# Potential resource leak: '<unassigned Closeable value>' may not be closed with SpringApplication.run(...)

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, memory-leaks

I've configured Eclipse to warn "Potential resource leak".

My Spring Boot main method has this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}
```

Eclipse detects this line as: `Potential resource leak: '<unassigned Closeable value>' may not be closed`

If I setup this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try(ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args)){
        
    }
}
```

Spring Boot starts and ends immediately

```
2020-06-25 14:02:28.336  INFO 9108 --- [main] demo.App                      : Started App in 50.426 seconds (JVM running for 51.605)
2020-06-25 14:02:28.403  INFO 9108 --- [main] org.mongodb.driver.connection : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:207}] to localhost:27017 because the pool has been closed.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I've solved it this way:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App implements Closeable {

    private static ConfigurableApplicationContext run;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        run = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        run.close();
    }

}
```

But I prefer a more elegant way.

Comment: Same problem, same solution! It works! Did you find "a more elegant way"?